# разделить строку на части

Tags: c#

есть строка например:

"первый","второй","123,67"

надое ее превратить в массив из 3 элементов разделителем должна служить запятая и элементы вытащить из ковычек. Причем запятая внутри кавычек не должна быть разделителем элементов. Т.е должно получиться

- первый
- второй
- 123,67

Разделить строку с разделителем ',' можно просто командой Split(new char{','}), но как поступить с этой же строкой с кавычками? Прогонять ее через цикл как массив байтов не хочется. Есть какое нибудь стандартное решение?

Comment: Это похоже на [csv](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSV). Так что следует использовать какой-нибудь csv-парсер.

Comment: Ну если формат всегда одинаковый, можно такой вариант с разделителем по `","`: `string[] arr = str.Substring(1, str.Length - 2).Split(new string[] { "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать регулярные выражения:

```
var input =  "\"первый\", \"второй\", \"123,67\"";
var output = new List<string>();
var csvSplit = new Regex("((?<=\")[^\"]*(?=\"(,|$)+)|(?<=,|^)[^,\"]*(?=,|$))", RegexOptions.Compiled);

foreach (Match match in csvSplit.Matches(input)) 
    output.Add(match.Value.TrimStart(','));

foreach (var i in output)
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Результат:

```
первый 
второй 
123,67
```

Или как советуют использовать csv парсер, например [CSVHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)

Answer (score 1):

Если формат стандартизирован, то можно сделать Split не по символу, а по строке "," - т.к. она и будет разделять элементы. 
Сперва удалив первую и последнюю кавычку - т.к. они не будут убраны Split'ом

```
"\"первый\",\"второй\",\"123,67\"".Trim('"').Split(new [] { "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
```